# Orchard - Creating Query Programmatically

Tags: module, orchardcms

I am creating a custom module in Orchard. After I enable my module I would like to create a query programmatically.

I do that in my Migrations.cs file thanks to implementation of IDependency interface.

I am able to create the query but I do I programmatically set filters of that query?

```
var announcementsQuery = _contentManager.Create("Query");
announcementsQuery.As<TitlePart>().Title = "Announcements";
_contentManager.Publish(announcementsQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do this:

```
var announcementsQuery = _contentManager.Create("Query");
                announcementsQuery.As<TitlePart>().Title = "Announcements";
                announcementsQuery.As<QueryPart>().ContentItem.ContentType = "Announcement";
                var filterGroupRecord = new FilterGroupRecord();
                var filterRecord = new FilterRecord()
                    {
                        Category = "Content",
                        Type = "ContentTypes",
                        Description = "Announcement",
                        Position = 1,
                        State = "<Form><Description>Announcement</Description><ContentTypes>Announcement</ContentTypes></Form>"
                    };
                filterGroupRecord.Filters.Insert(0, filterRecord);
                announcementsQuery.As<QueryPart>().FilterGroups.Insert(0, filterGroupRecord);
```